# One eye icon for multiple fields in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a password and confirm password input field and I am trying to use the eye icon in the password field to toggle visibility for both fields.

I currently have the code:

```
const togglePassword = document.querySelector('#togglePassword');
const password = document.querySelector('#pswd');

togglePassword.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
  password.setAttribute('type', type);
  this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
});
```

to toggle the visibility for the password, but I am not sure how to use it for the second field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work for multiple elements you need to use `querySelectorAll()` with a `class`selector. This returns a collection of elements which you can then loop through to add your event listener.

Note that you will need to use some DOM traversal methods to relate the clicked icon to the password field. I've used a combination of `closest()` and `querySelector()` in the following example, but this would need to be updated depending on exactly how your HTML is structured.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.togglePassword').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let password = el.closest('.toggle-container').querySelector('.pswd');
    const type = password.getAttribute('type') === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
    password.setAttribute('type', type);
    e.target.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="toggle-container">
  <input type="password" class="pswd" />
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-eye-slash togglePassword"></i>
</div>

<div class="toggle-container">
  <input type="password" class="pswd" />
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-eye-slash togglePassword"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! What exactly does the "example-parent" class represent in this example?

Comment: A parent element to `.togglePassword` with a class on it.

Comment: I've added a HTML example to the question so you can see how the structure should look.